# View not updating on collection add if done after view create in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am not able to figure out what is going on here:

```
var times;
 var t;
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var timeObj = Backbone.Model.extend({
               setTime: function(time){
                   this.time = time;
                   return 1;
               },
               getTime: function(){
                  return this.time;
               },
               addTime: function(minutes){
                   return new Date(this.time.getTime() + minutes*60000);
               }

      });

      var timeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: timeObj,
      });

      t = new timeObj();

      var now = new Date();



      times = new timeCollection();

      t.setTime(now);




    var outputView = Backbone.View.extend({
          el: "#output",
          collection: times,
          render: function(html){
             this.$el.html(html);

          },
          renderTimes: function(){

              var that = this;
              this.collection.each(function(model){
              console.log("g");
                     console.log(model.getTime());
                    that.$el.append(model.getTime()+"<br>");
              });
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderTimes());
         }
      });
      times.add(t);
      var t30 = t.addTime(30);
      var t2 = new timeObj();
      t2.setTime(t30);

 var output = new outputView();

times.add(t2);

}):
```

It does work if I put the add line above the output create.

Is this how it is supposed to work or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have small a syntax error here:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderTimes());
```

Should be this (basically just need to remove the `()` which messed up your callback since the function call returned either `null` or `undefined` to your listener when you wanted the actual function to callback later):

```
this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderTimes);
```

Also here is a jsFiddle with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/a9YAV/

**Edit 2**

Here is an updated jsFiddle that illustrates things better: http://jsfiddle.net/a9YAV/1/

Change one I made was:

```
 initialize: function(){
     this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderTimes); 
     this.renderTimes();
 }
```

You need to make sure to call `renderTimes` in initialize to load the initial elements

Also added a small delay to adding the second time object here to make sure `renderTimes` was being called a second time:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    times.add(t2);     
}, 1000);
```